# Using OWL API to import ontology

Tags: owl-api

I'm using the OWL API, and I have an ontology. I'm trying to import another ontology the way we do in protege, i.e. select the OWL File locally and then import it. Is this possible with the OWL API

I'm using the import declaration,

```
OWLImportsDeclaration importDeclaraton = ontology.getFactory().getOWLImportsDeclaration(IRI.create("/home/noor/Dropbox/TaggingCaseStudy/Programs/TextBasedMA/files/ontologies/OBMA2/photo1.owl"));
```

But I'm getting an error, it is not taking the file locally,

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://semanticweb.org/home/noor/Dropbox/TaggingCaseStudy/Programs/TextBasedMA/files/ontologies/OBMA2/photo1.owl
```

Answer (score 2):

Your IRI is relative, not absolute - it needs to start with `file:` for a file to be found. Relative IRIs will be resolved against the base IRI at the time of loading, which in your case creates the URL which you can see in the error.
Try making the IRI absolute, or use indirection by using the actual ontology IRI in the import and using an `IRIMapper` to point at the file.

E.g., if your ontology has an IRI of `http://example.com/myontology`, use

```
OWLImportsDeclaration importDeclaraton = ontology.getFactory().getOWLImportsDeclaration(IRI.create("http://example.com/myontology"));
```

to create the imports declaration, and add an `IRIMapper` to your `OWLOntologyManager` for resolving it when loading the ontology:

```
manager.addIRIMapper(new SimpleIRIMapper(IRI.create("http://example.com/myontology"),
       IRI.create("file:///actual/path/to/file.owl"));
```

Edit: with OWLAPI 4, this looks like:

```
manager.getIRIMappers().add(new SimpleIRIMapper(IRI.create("http://example.com/myontology"),
           IRI.create("file:///actual/path/to/file.owl"));
```

Javadoc for this can be found on the GitHub page

Comment: Is this valid with current OWL api updates? @Ignazio

Comment: I think the `OWLImportsDeclaration` should also be updated, since `getFactory()` seems to be deprecated

Comment: I would but it's not clear which type ontology is in the original question. OWLOntology does not appear to have a factory accessor. Anyway, any OWLDataFactory reference will do, they produce equivalent objects.